# Firebase dynamic link synchronously?

Tags: android, firebase, synchronous, firebase-dynamic-links

im trying to use Firebase Dynamic Links to open a screen in the app, like so:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink(intent)
        .addOnSuccessListener(activity) { pendingDynamicLinkData ->
            val uri = pendingDynamicLinkData?.link
            val fragment = fragmentFromUri(uri)
            fm.replace(fragment)
        }
```

This however is asynchronous. So my main screen is visible for a split second and then switches to a deeplinked one.

Is there way to avoid this? Can I extract the deep link synchrously? When I'm already installed I do see the intent.data parameter, however after fresh install the data is null, and only the firebase callback works. How does it even work if the intent has null extras? Is there some network check or whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load the dynamic link contents synchronously (that I know of at least).

The usual solution is to show a more neutral screen (for example a blank screen, or something that says "loading" in fairly neutral theming) while resolving the dynamic link, and then transitioning to either the fragment indicated in the activity, or the actual main screen.

Comment: Do you mean to show that loading UI implictly on every FooActivity start until dynamic link is processed or not? That's terrible UX. Most of all dynamic link will be like a 1% use case.

Comment: Or do I know that the intent contains some data that will resolve into a dynamic link? (so I don't effect every flow)

Comment: von Puffelen hi, sorry to bother you, but is there a way to know the intent contains the dynamic link, so I can show some intermediate UI until its resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```
 fun getDeepLink(intent: Intent): String? {
        return try {
            val task = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(intent)
            val deepLink = task.result.link?:return null
            val landingSection: String = deepLink.getQueryParameter("your_link")?:return null
            landingSection
        }catch (e:Exception){
            null
        }
    }
```